# Pip install successfull but ... ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pydrive' in Python

Tags: python, pip

I tried several options to access to Google Drive via Python, using

1. PyDrive
2. google-api-client

In both options the pip install has been executed successfully.

However, when I initiate the code in Jupyter notebook (or Visual Studio):

1.

```
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
gauth = GoogleAuth()           
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)`
```

2. 

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from googleapiclient.http import MediaIoBaseDownload
```

I get either

1.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pydrive'
```

2. ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'googleapiclient'

Any idea where I'm going wrong?

On the Google console I did set up the service account, ...

Don't get my head around what may cause the issue.

Comment: " pip install has been executed successfully". You aren't saying how you are doing install, the specific command or where & how it was run. You are just describing a symptom. Did you run `%pip install pydrvie` in a new cell in the notebook and then restarted the kernel? And my other concern is that valid? [This shows that hasn't been updated in nearly a decade](https://pypi.org/project/PyDrive/#history), and that is concerning. What about `%pip install PyDrive2`, based on [here](https://pypi.org/project/PyDrive2/)?

Answer (score 2):

Verify the Environment:
Ensure that you are operating within the appropriate Python environment. Confirming the correct environment is crucial for the smooth execution of your code.

Pro Tip: Consider employing a virtual environment to address this concern. Activate the virtual environment using the command "**source venv/bin/activate**".